# C# Find text inside html class on website and click href link

Tags: c#, phantomjs

I'm making an application that can find an item on a website if the item name and colour matches the one set inside the application.
[image: Each item on the website is inside an article as seen on this screenshot]

If the item name is set as "backpack" and colour set as "green" the application should find a match on the page and click the link. The website is this: [Click](http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags)

I would prefer doing this in C# with http requests or something similar. I would also do PhantomJS if anyone has a better solution using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium, it basically allows you to act like a user with actual web browser. http://www.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Is that a headless browser? Also how would I do what my question asks using selenium? Thanks

Comment: It's not headless, it's an actual browser but you can define actions to run on it, such as: navigating clicking buttons change classes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like mentioned below with the help of `XPath`:

```
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags");
        var backpack= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//h1//a[contains(., 'Backpack') or contains(., 'Backpack')]"));
        var colorGreen = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[contains(@class,'inner-article')]//p//a[contains(., 'Acid Green') or contains(., 'Acid Green')]"));
        if (backpack.Text == "Backpack" && colorGreen.Text == "Acid Green")
            colorGreen.Click();
```

It is a tested code, it successfully finds the required values within tags, clicks and moves to that page.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I could use that in C# or see if that works?

Comment: My answer is in c# not in any other language.

Comment: Sorry I can't get it to work. What is the driver? When I check google it says selenium.

Comment: Its an instance of `PhantomJS`, I don't know why it doesn't work for you because I answered what you described in your question, if there is something else, let me know.